# Is it possible to throw an exception using short hand condition operator? c#

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am trying to use the short hand operator to check a condition in order to throw an exception.

```
throw (result == false) ? new Exception("Result is false.") : null;
```

The lines following the above line, I receive an "unreachable code detected error".

I'm thinking that if I "throw null" if the condition is not met, it is still throwing an exception.

Any better way to do this short hand?

Comment: Why do you want to do it in a ternary operation? Just use `if (Result == false) throw...`. When you find yourself struggling to make something fit into a ternary operator, it usually means you shouldn't be using one in the first place.

Comment: FWIW, you could create a stub function containing something like `throw arg == null ? new ArgumentNullException() : new ArgumentException(); // To do: Implement function.`. Any code after that would certainly be unreachable. Other than a stub to be replaced by useful code later it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @HABO the problem with helper functions that throw is that they end up in the stack trace, which muddies the source of the error later.

Comment: I'd like to add to @KenWhite's answer: you need to know when to use it. Sure, it's nice to avoid writing `if/else` statements all over, but it can hurt readability of your code. This isn't JavaScript where character count matters (to download smaller files), so prefer to focus on code readability over saving few bytes and maybe a second of my time. I always try to write my code to be read by others (keeping to coding conventions, commenting/documenting...), even when I work alone. I'd advise you to do the same. It's also much easier to adapt once you start working with a group of programmers.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I wasn't thinking of a helper function. I was thinking of roughing out a class and wanting to put something in a function body, to be replaced shortly by functional code, that is slightly more than a `// TODO` comment. In this case, always throwing an exception so that you know you've hit something not yet implemented while checking for a null argument. It would be more appropriate to `throw new NotImplementedException("Try again soon." + (arg == null ? " fyi: arg was null." : ""));`.

Comment: @HABO oh I see. Yeah, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this because you are `throw`ing either an exception or a null and in either case the code below is always unreachable. You could simply do this on one line:

```
if (!result) throw new Exception("Result is false.");
```

This even ends up being less typed characters

Comment: Marked as answer. Easiest answers are always in front of you. My brain power is dwindling this late in the day :|

Comment: This doesn't work with `StyleCopAnalyzers`

Comment: @Yola assuming what you mean is the code causes StyleCopAnalyzers to complain about formatting; the code works and functions as expected. If StyleCopAnalyzers complain, that's outside the scope of this answer as the question was about a short one liner to throw an exception based on condition. With that said, if the code actually doesn't execute any longer, that's probably because this answer is 8 years old and language specs change over time but I'm "almost" certain this still executes as expected. You're free to add exceptions to StyleCopAnalyzers rules to ignore this as well